# Hibernate getting value twice while user has multiple roles

Tags: java, hibernate

My User Table is as follows

```
public class EUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userName;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserRole> roles;
    @OneToOne
    private EUser approvedBy;
}
```

now i am trying to get all user from `EUser` table. I am getting some user more than one time who has more than one `UserRole`

to get the list i am using following method

```
private SessionFactory session;
session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from EUser").list();
```

How can i fix that so that i don't get same user more than one time in the list??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the way joins are handled internally. A solution is just to dump your List in a Set to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: how to dump List in a Set??

Comment: `Set resultAsSet = new HashSet(resultAsList);`

But note that you will lose the order, so if this matters, you should consider using `LinkedHashSet` instead of HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

there is many to many dependency between your UserRole and Euser so you will definately get duplicate entries, so you have to filter it in your logic after fetching it from DB

Comment: how can i filter that? could you please help me on that??

Comment: @LynAs you can either parse it one by one iterating it and remove the duplicates or you can convert the List into set http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-list-to-set-arraylist-to-hastset/

Comment: yes its working thanks but steph answered first so i am accepting his answer. thank you